# How can I made my sprite walk normaly in python's module : pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

First excuse-mo for my english, I'm French. I have alittle problem : I am maiding a 2d rpg in pygame and I made my map with many little image of grass, tree... But when I put the real size of textures on the screen my hero sprite have a jerky walk so I try to reduce de size of the bloc :my sprite walk normaly but the texture were very ugly so I'll ask you this question : do you know how solve it ? My main code :

```
import pygame
from game import Game
from level import Level
pygame.init()

lvl = Level()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080, 720))
pygame.display.set_caption("RPG") 
game = Game()
running = True
lvl.generer()
print(game.player.rect)


while running:
    lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0)
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT) and game.player.rect.x + game.player.rect.width < 1080:
        game.player.move_right()
        #print(game.player.rect.x)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT) and game.player.rect.x > 0:
        game.player.move_left()
        #print(game.player.rect.x)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_DOWN):
        game.player.move_down()
        #screen.scroll(0, -game.player.velocity)
        #print(game.player.rect.y)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_UP):
        game.player.move_up()
        #screen.scroll(0, game.player.velocity)
        #print(game.player.rect.y)

    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             game.pressed[event.key] = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False
```

And my player class (who inherited of game class but I d'ont put my game class on this post)

```
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.game = game
        self.health = 100
        self.maxHealth = 100
        self.attack = 10
        self.velocity = 100
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 300)) 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 400
        self.rect.y = 500

    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_profileLeft/player_profile_left.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 300)) 

    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_profileRight/player_profile_right.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 300)) 

    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 300)) 

    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_back/player_dos.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (300, 300))
```

and my game class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
from player import Player

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_players.add(self.player)
        self.pressed = {}


    def check_collision(self, sprite, group):
        return pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly, you aren't using [var] = pygame.time.Clock() and [var].tick([some number]), which limits the FPS. I think your issue is that the FPS is fluctuating and causing lag.

Comment: so I need tu put a big or a little number in [var].tick([some number]) ?

Comment: OK I was try your proposal : I put clock = pygame.time.Clock() just above of the loop on main.py and clock.tick() just on the first line of the loop, I try with 1, 10, 20, 40, and 100

Comment: Hmm strange. clock is supposed to be outside the loop and clock.tick() just above the update statement (at the end) but it shouldn't make a big difference. The bigger the number, the smoother the graphics. 120 is what most computers should be able to handle. Not sure how to help you though, sorry

Comment: I guess you can try putting your fps on the caption/screen and seeing if it fluctuates. 

https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/46sdo7/how_do_i_display_fps_in_pygame_191_for_python_27/